# Do packages outside functions refresh on firebase deploy --only functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Let's assume the following **`index.js`** on the Firebase's functions folder:

```js
const data = require('./hosting/_data.js'); 

exports.functionA = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    response.status(200).send(data[html]);
    
});

exports.functionB = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    response.status(200).send(data[error]);
    
});
```

If I modify **`_data.js`** and deploy the changes using `firebase deploy ---only hosting,functions:functionA`, will both functions see the changes in **`_data.js`**? Or only `functionA` will be affected?

How does Firebase manage these situations?

Answer (score 1):

If only `functionA` is deployed, only the container for `functionA` is rebuilt, so I'd expect only that function to get the new `node_modules`.